# How to use "query_string" to query documents and filter out the first element of the list field

Tags: elasticsearch

In my Elasticsearch, I have a document like this:

```
          "field_4" : [
            "ip_address",
            "127.0.0.1"
          ],
          "field_1" : 6522000300012,
          "field_2" : "asdfa",
          "field_26" : [
            "address",
            "HongKong"
          ]
```

and my body is:

```
body = {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{"query_string": {"query": "*p*"}}]
                }
            }
        }
```

Now my query can find all fields with string "P", but for list type fields, I don't want to query their first element.

I mean the above document can't be queryed beause the string "p" only exists in the first element of the list type filed_4.

Is there a way to write a query that search without the first element of the list in Elasticsearch?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-query-string-query) supports `fields`   to query on specific fields. So you can specify only those field that you want to query

```
body = {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{"query_string": {"query": "*p*","fields":["field_1","field_2","field_26"]}}]
                }
            }
        }
```